# Excel VBA macro to display filtered information from back end table

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking for some help with a project I am currently working on.  I am creating a presentation worksheet in which I display counts of parts that have reached various status'.  IE, the part is past due, the part needs a contract, the part is with design, etc etc.  In all i have 8 different status's that an individual part can be in base on certian criteria.  I have already created toggles to indicate which status a specific part is in and I use that toggle to display my counts in my display.

Currently I have coded the display to toggle based on a drop down, so the data changes by our workgroups.  What i want to do is create code that will upon a click look at the count in the clicked cell and display below the specific parts accociated with that could.  For example if group 1 has a count of 5 in the cell for status "The part is with design" I want to have those 5 specific parts and some other data accociated with them dispaly in a table I created below this master dispaly.  All data is housed on a seperate data sheet so really i just need to know how to filter, then copy the specifc parts of the data I want and re-display it.

The table I want to display it in is called "selection" which currently has 3 clomuns, ID, Part, and Bid#.  The table I Would be pulling the data from is on a seperate worksheet called Data, which in the end will be hidden from the user.  Is there anyone here who could assist me with this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Show us your code, sample data, the logic and expected results. That would be better than writing a *novel* :)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to have your data all in the current spreadsheet - and use filtering to winnow down to the rows that match the conditions you desire.  To do this, add a hidden column to the sheet, and set its formula to something like:

=IF(PArea="- ALL AREA PATHS -",TRUE,IFERROR(IF(FIND(PArea,[@[Producing Area]])>0,TRUE,FALSE),FALSE))

Your selector drop-down list should be a named range (the PArea here).

Then, you could add a button that runs the following code - I label that button "Filter" - so that the user knows to select a filter criteria, and then click filter.  This runs code like the following:

```
'Consumer Area
If Range("PArea") = "- ALL AREA PATHS -" Then
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table_Dependenciesl").Range.AutoFilter Field:=22
Else
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table_Dependenciesl").Range.AutoFilter Field:=22, _
        Criteria1:="TRUE"
End If
```

The combination of the cell in the hidden column (value = True on match, blank on no-match) and the VBA code then hide all rows that don't have the filter column set to true.  In the example, the text "- ALL AREA PATHS -" is added to the drop down range that drives the dropdown box @ PArea - and the logic in the cell formula knows that the value should be true if all values are selected - otherwise has to match the specific selected value.

The autoFilter command takes one or two args - field # is the column # (starting @ 1) and the optional criteria causes the filter to be set to wherever the hidden column with our formula displays "True".  When criteria is omitted, the filter is undone and that column no longer contributes to rows being filtered.  Note the line continuation character _ above - so you don't pull your hair out.